# What are general techniques of structuring an image classification Neural Network for very large numbers of output classes?

Tags: neural-networks, image-recognition, softmax

I am aware of Neural Networks that have 100K+ classes and I would like to build one myself (yes, I have lots of training data) but I am unsure which technique to use because most of the nets I have previously built struggle when the number of classes exceeds a few thousand. One idea I have is a hierarchical system with multiple nets but that seems like an inefficient architecture (maybe it is currently the best).

For real world context, I was at my local grocery store and they had a new automated shopping cart system that used machine vision (I assume some type of NN) to identify every item in the store (see article that I was able to find). https://bit.ly/3V7Z7VI

I have done some research on techniques and found these threads that both mention hierarchical softmax as a way to achieve large numbers of classes: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3b2odj/most_output_classes_in_a_neural_network/ https://www.quora.com/Can-neural-networks-have-thousands-of-output-classes

This academic article does propose one technique besides a softmax hierarchy (Random Projection): https://www.ecva.net/papers/eccv_2020/papers_ECCV/papers/123680698.pdf